# seleniumElement.click() wasnot work vb.net

Tags: vb.net, selenium

what wrong of code that make this error pleze
error ;click is not member of openqa.selenium

```
Imports System.Text
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome


Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim driver As IWebDriver
        driver = New ChromeDriver
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://m.facebook.com/")
        Dim element As IWebDriver = driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_0_b"))
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
        element.Click()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type IWebDriver does not have a click method. Change the type for the `element` variable in the declaration to IWebElement:

```
Dim element As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("u_0_b"))
```